# Conditional Expression not working in Azure DevOps 2019

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-devops-server-2019

I am trying to conditionally execute a step in Azure DevOps Server 2019. I followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops-2019).

I am passing a runTests parameter to my template. At first I tried a condition on the Job, but that doesn't work, because it will always use the default in the template, so I switched to a conditional expression. My job YAML now looks like

```
- job: TestJob
  pool: 'mypool'    
  #condition: eq('${{ parameters.runTests }}', 'true')
  workspace:
    clean: all
  steps:
  - script: echo ${{ parameters.runTests }}
  - script: echo ${{ eq(parameters.runTests, 'true') }}
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.runTests, 'true') }}:
    - task: UiPathTest@2
      inputs:
        testTarget: 'TestProject'
        orchestratorConnection: 'Orch'
        testProjectPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$(projectPath)'
        folderName: $(folderName)
```

I added the lines to echo the parameter, and the result of the expression. The parameter value is 'true', which is correct, but the result of `eq(parameters.runTests, 'true')` is always false. My YAML is almost identical to the example though. Any ideas what might be wrong? I do not have any errors. The step just does not exist.

Comment: In your condition, remove the `'${{ ... }}'` around the parameter name. The condition syntax will understand you're trying to reference a variable there. Optionally add `$[ ...]` around the complete condition.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. 
"Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings. /project-pipeline-template.yaml@templates (Line: 29, Col: 5): Unexpected value 'if eq(parameters.runTests, 'true')'"

Comment: This is Azure DevOps Server 2019

Comment: why is your condition line commented out with the # ?

Comment: Because that doesn't work with arguments in DevOps Server 2019. I was testing it out and left that in. Server 2019 will always use the default value in that condition, instead of what is passed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, what made the differences was

```
variables:
  runTests: 'true'

---

jobs:
- template: template.yaml@templates  # Template reference
  parameters:
    runTests: $(runTests)
```

vs skipping the variable

```
---

jobs:
- template: template.yaml@templates  # Template reference
  parameters:
    runTests: 'true'
```

I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a similar pipeline, however, added parameter definition and specified type for parameter value.

```
parameters:
- name: runTests
  type: boolean

jobs:
  - job: TestJob
    #condition: eq('${{ parameters.runTests }}', 'true')
    workspace:
      clean: all
    steps:
    - script: echo ${{ parameters.runTests }}
    - script: echo ${{ eq(parameters.runTests, True) }}
    - ${{ if eq(parameters.runTests, True) }}:
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            echo 'Hello world'
```

When triggering pipeline I check runTests box [image: runTests-box-checked]

The following steps execute as expected and both `echo` steps return `True` [image: passed-steps-example]
Plus conditional bash script is executed as well.

I suggest setting this parameter as boolean and comparing it to boolean `True` instead of string `'true'`

Comment: Is that on Azure DevOps Server 2019? That is where I am having the issue. I don't think I can define the parameters like that in 2019. I am also passing the argument by using the file as a template.